# Set the receiver email on Paypal REST API

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway

I use Paypal REST API to manage payment on my web app

```
var payment = {
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  //"receiver_email":  "business@place.fr",
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://yoururl.com/execute",
    "cancel_url": "http://yoururl.com/cancel"
  },

  "transactions": [{
    "item_list": {
        "items": [{
            "name": "item",
            "sku": "item",
            "price": "1.00",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": 1
        }]
    },
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "1.06",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "1.00",
          "tax": "0.03",
          "shipping": "0.03"
        }
    },
    "description": "This is the payment description."
  }]
};

paypal.payment.create(payment, function (error, payment) { ... }
```

But I can find a way to set the payment receiver email. All the payments go to account link to  my Paypal app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not a supported feature in PayPal's REST API.

You can use Permissions API to run DoDirectPayment requests for other users. However, the user would have to be approved for Payments Pro.

Comment: can you give more details about that ?